# Go to odd or even week flash as3 cs6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

Please help me..! Could you help me with the as3 script how to go to frame labeled "odd week" or "even week"? Case: If this week (from monday to sunday) is the odd week, when I press the button, it will automaticaly go to frame labeled "odd week". So, If this week (from monday to sunday) is not the odd week, it will automatically go to frame labeled "even week". It doesn't matter odd or even is to be the first. Thank you very much for you kindness.

Comment: **gotoAndStop("odd week");**

Comment: Are you asking how to know which day's **number** belongs to either an odd or even week? Example: day 5 and day 17 belongs to odd weeks (1 and 3).

Comment: If this week from monday to sunday is the odd week, the next week will be the even week. So when i click the button this day (because this day belongs to odd week) it will automatically go to "odd week". But if i click the button on monday next week, it will automatically go to "even week". Because the days next week belong to the even week.

Comment: @AndiWidodo what is stopping me from answering you is the not knowing how you get the day of month like when you say _"click the button on monday next week"_. **(1)** Does each button have a number or some `.name =` given to it? **(2)** You need a bunch of **IF** statement. Example any week 2 day number  is larger than 7 AND smaller than 15 so... `if ( (dayNum > 7) && (dayNum <15) ) { ..do week 2 stuff here... } `